# How shall I add Java class file?

Tags: java, go, automated-tests, bdd, goland

I am using Goland IDE to build microservice in Go.  If I have to write tests in Java, can Goland IDE support that. I don't see the support for Java in Goland. But wanted to check with folks who are experienced in Goland.

Comment: Goland is a Go IDE and there is no reason to expect it to support Java since the languages are completely unrelated. Use a Java IDE to write Java code.

Comment: You also won't be able to reference any Java code from your Go code or vice-versa, so the value of actually creating a Java class to test Go code is likely zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a Java file in GoLand, you need to invoke *File | New | File* and enter the whole name with an extension, e.g., *MyFactoryBean.java*. But keep in mind that GoLand doesn't offer Java support, so you won't get syntax highlighting, code completion, and so on. [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), on the contrary, supports both Java and Go at the same time, so you might want to use it to work with both languages simultaneously.

[image]